# Filtering in UITableview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am new to iOS app development.
I am developing an app which will show a list of companies.
This list is shown in a `UITableviewController`.
It has many labels like company name, their field in industry etc.

Once the list is displayed i want to give an option to filter based on their fields i.e.
listing all telecom industry or etc based on my login.

If the user is from a telecom industry i want to show all telecom related companies if user is from a service industry I want to show all service related industry and so on.

I want to give either a drop down on top or buttons or anything that will be easy to see and understand for the user to filter this out.

Please give me an ideas and if possible tutorials to achieve it.

Deeply appreciate your efforts,
Thanks

Comment: You need to create a logic to edit your datasource and then reload the tableView to reflect new datasource. This will get you started :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, you can keep all the content in `NSArray` and you can put a set of buttons or a drop down list ( you can use [NIDropDown](https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown)) if you really want to have a professional look to categorize filters.

User will select any filter from the list and you need to filter the NSArray to extract the required information based on the action performed by the user on drop down list and reload the data in the UITableview.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added buttons to the header and based on the button clicked I am filtering my table contents :)

Comment: Enjoy.:) I really like NIDropDown and used in many of my applications.

Answer (score 0):

follow these links to know how to create tables.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iOS_5_iPhone_Table_View_Application

talking about filters , you can create two view controllers. On first you show all fileds that are present in a table view and user can select by tapping on anyone of them.

use delegate method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. inside this method write the code to move to the next screen where details can be shown as per the user's selection.

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
{ 
 nextviewController = [secondDetailedView alloc]init];
[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller: nextviewController Animated:Yes ];

}
```

now obviously you need a navigation controller that can be created in appdelegate method. What data has to be shown on next screen in table is up to you (on user's selection).